# how can make new value not reference in inserting value

Tags: c++

i'm solving a problem, and i need function make graph which connected with the other vertex using vector.
but when i test, it crash with an exception, "0xC0000005" and memory of vector's element be unreadable.
i guess it caused by that the way i do doesn't copy deep.

here is source code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    int _N, _Q = 0; 
    

    
    std::cin >> _N >> _Q;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>* videoList = new std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>[_N];
    


    for (int i = 0; i < _N - 1; i++) {
        
        int p_i, q_i, r_i;
        
        std::cin >> p_i >> q_i >> r_i;


        videoList[p_i].emplace_back(std::pair<int, int>(q_i, r_i));

        videoList[q_i].emplace_back(std::pair<int, int>(p_i, r_i));
        

    }

    std::cout << "TEST" << std::endl;
    std::cout << videoList[0][0].first << std::endl;


    delete[] videoList;
    //std::cout << videoList[2] << std::endl;
    return 0;
    
}
```

and here is example input

```
4 3
1 2 3
2 3 2
2 4 4
```

im trying to use pointer but i failed..

Comment: Creating vector on the heap doesn't make sense here. For the problem, try using `at` member function. Change `videoList[p_i]` to `videoList.at(p_i)`.

Comment: I don't see the need of using `new` here. Is there a particular reason you're using it here?

Comment: its used to create dynamic vector array

Comment: But you could just wrap that in a vector instead of allocating as an array.

Comment: use `std::vector` and get rid of all `new` and `delete`

Comment: Fixing that won't fix the issue. Enabling address sanitizer identifies the problem pretty much immediately: https://godbolt.org/z/3K6on8PqY -- you're indexing past your array in the call to `emplace_back`. Using `.at()` would also identify it. Remember that array indexing starts at zero. So if your array is size 4, you cannot use the index 4.

Comment: all you made my day guys, i solved this problem by rapping std::vector declare instead array. and using .at() is not working for me.(maybe miss of declare with using std::vector)

Comment: `std::vector<std::pair<int, int>>* ` why would you even create a pointer to a vector? Also do yourself another favor. do NOT use std::pair outside of template programming, just declare a struct of your own with two member variables with readable names

Comment: @PepijnKramer the pointer points to first element of a c-style array. Though, quesiton remains, why do they mix `std::vector` and c-arrays

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The question remains, why are teachers still teaching "C" arrays (and naked new/delete). I mean std::vector has been in since 1998 and std::array has been in since 2011. So there should be no reason for new developers to learn about "C" style arrays (unless they need to interact with legacy code)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I suppose a big factor is psychologic. Working with c-arrays one devleops arcane skills that are needed to avoid all kinds of errors. Once one reached a certain level in those skill there is a strong reluctance to trust someone who states you wouldnt need those skills. I mean, obviously one does need to know how to avoid segfaults and double free and etc when you work with c-arrays. Its not easy to realize that the premise is already false (no need to work with c-arrays in the first place)

Comment: The proble is with the data you are feeding into your application. You create an array of 4 vectors, to store the remaining data. You then use values to enter the data, which uses the first two numbers as array indices. The first two use offsets 1 and 2, the next use 2 and 3, and the last use 2 and 4. But 4 is not a valid offset, since an array of 4 elements can only use offsets 0 to 3.

Comment: The big factor is that most teacher are teaching datastructures and want the low level support of C++ (basically the "C" part) so they can (they think) explain all about pointers and memory layouts. Which is fine but they totally fail to teach that this is not the way C++ should ever be used in practice. And students... they stick to what they learned first.